# Python3 not checking for number in list properly in if statement

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I am currently building an ATM program, where the user inputs their pin number. If that number is in the list pin_no, then the user gains access to his/her account. However, I seem to have problems around line 70, where the program is checking if what is inputted is inside the list. Anything that is inputted is taken incorrect, and python is not checking if the number inputted is in the list. Is this because the list is all the way at the top of the program, to make it global, or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pin_no = [1234, 4321, 9876]     # Neil, John, Sue


class Account:



    def __init__(self, balance, name, cash_in_hand):

        self.name = name

        self.balance = balance

        self.cash_in_hand = cash_in_hand





def checker():



    proceed_1 = False
    proceed_2 = False
    end = False



    while proceed_1 == False and proceed_2 == False and end == False:

        print('Card Inserted?')

        inp_card = input('Y / N > ')



        if inp_card == 'y' or inp_card == 'Y':

            proceed_1 = True

            print('\nPlease input your PIN')

            inp_pin = input('PIN > ')



            # Fixed

            if inp_pin in list(pin_no):

                proceed_2 = True

                welcome()

            else:

                c = 3

                # Fixed

                while c > 1:

                    c -= 1

                    print('Incorrect Pin. You have', c, 'attempt/s left.')

                    retry = input('PIN >')

                    if retry in pin_no:
                        welcome()
                    else:
                        pass

        elif inp_card == 'n' or inp_card == 'N':

            print('Please input your card')

        else:

            print('Invalid Option!')


def welcome():
    print('Welcome')

    print('---------------')

    print('1. Check Balance')

    print('2. Withdraw funds')

    print('3. Deposit funds')

    print('4. Exit')

    response = input('Choice> ')

    if response == '1':  # TODO REMOVE

        pass

    elif response == '2':

        pass  # TODO REMOVE

    elif response == '3':

        pass  # TODO REMOVE

    elif response == '4':

        pass

    else:

        print('Invalid Option!')







checker()





# Neil's Account Test Data

neil = Account(1.00, 'Neil', 50.00)



# John's Account Test Data

john = Account(100.00, 'John', 1.00)



# Sue's Account Test Data

Sue = Account(50.00, 'Sue', 50.00)
```

Comment: Your problem may be related to difference between a string and a number. '1234' is not equal to 1234. You have to convert the input string to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `input()` returns a string. To address this issue, you can either make pin_no a list of strings, like `pin_no = ["1234", "4321", "9876"]`, or convert the output of input() to an integer, like `inp_pin = int(input('PIN > '))`.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
inp_pin = input('PIN > ')
```

inp_pin was returning as a string.

For the program to read it, it had to be read as an int.

Thus, the solution is:

```
 inp_pin = int(input('PIN > '))
```